# SQL Query to pick a row based on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way in SQL to choose a particular row by checking the condition in sequence?

Condition: choose 1 FC, min(status),max(Version),max(CD),max(MD)

Table Data:

```
FC  Status  Version CD  MD
1   999     23      20  13
1   500     10      22  15
1   400     23      19  11
1   500     15      18  9
1   400     19      17  12
1   400     19      16  13
1   400     23      17  30
```

Output should be:

```
FC  Status  Version CD  MD
1   400     23      19  11
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
order by status asc, version desc, cd desc, md desc;
```

If you want to do this per `FC`, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fc
                                order by status asc, version desc, cd desc, md desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sql server has handy `with ties` and allows for row_number() in `Order by`. So

```
select top 1 with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() 
         over (partition by fc order by status asc, version desc, cd desc, md desc) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GROUP BY clause :

```
SELECT FC,min(status),max(Version),max(CD),max(MD)
FROM YOUR_table
GROUP BY FC
```

Comment: If you will look carefully, you will see that this is not what the OP is asking for.  the `CD` column is not the maximum value.